# Is it possible in php session to set expire time for a certain key/value?

Tags: php, session

We have an expire time for the whole session which erases all the session when time is up. But is there a way to give an expire time to a certain key? For example the session expires in 3 hours so all data will expire in 3 hours. But what if I want that the `$_SESSION['five_min_value']` key and its values to expire earlier than others? Is there a built in session way or have I to deal with that on myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not without handling the them manually. However you can set specific expire times for cookies. You could use cookies instead.

Answer (score 1):

try using cookies
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, security);